# Logically associate a coordinate frame to an image in matlab

Tags: matlab

how to logically associate a coordinate frame to an image such that origin lies in the center of the image in MATLAB?

```
A = phantom(128);
imshow(A);
```

How to generate the `axes` for image `A` and how to put an image with respect to the new coordinate system, with the center of the image at `(0,0)`.

Comment: If according to that I try to fire this command imshow(A, 'Xdata',[-64 64],'Ydata',[-64 64]); even then it is not specifying whether the coordinate system has been attached or not. I mean how to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the [`XData`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html#property_XData) and [`YData`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html#property_YData) properties of the image such that it will be shifted. By default, `imshow` will not show the underlying `axes`  so if you want to visualize those, you'll need to turn the axes visibility on.

```
imshow(A, 'XData', [-0.5 0.5] * size(A, 2), ...
          'YData', [-0.5 0.5] * size(A, 1));
axis on
```

If you need to do more than shift the image coordinates, you can use an [`imref2d`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imref2d-class.html) object to specify the transformation and then pass this as the second input to `imshow`

```
ref = imref2d(size(A),[-64 64], [-64 64]);
imshow(A, ref);
```

**Update**

If you want to be able to access data using this tranformed coordinate system, you'll have to use `interp2` to do that.

```
[x,y] = ref.worldToIntrinsic(2, -3);
value = interp2(A, x, y);
```

Comment: after this imref2d, will I  be able to access elements like A(-2,-3) ?

Comment: @M.B. No. Indexing still has to be done using integers.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly I was looking for...Thanks a ton @Suever..God bless u :)